# Setting lambdas for KeyVaultSecret on ReturnsAsync

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq, mstest

I'm using Moq 4.18.4 and I'm having trouble when setting the ReturnsAsync, it is showing to me the following error

> ISetup<SecretClient, Task<Response>>' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync' and the best extension method overload 'SequenceExtensions.ReturnsAsync<Func>(ISetupSequentialResult<Task<Func>>, Func)' requires a receiver of type 'Moq.Language.ISetupSequentialResult<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Func<Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.KeyVaultSecret>>>

I'm aware that the lambda function should have parameters, but no matter how I try to set them, I still get error results

```
public async Task GetCertsFromKeyVaultAsync()
  {
      // Arrange
      string certificateName = "MyCertificate";
      string base64PrivateKey = "BASE64_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE";
      byte[] privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64PrivateKey);
      X509Certificate2 expectedCertificate = new X509Certificate2(privateKeyBytes);


      // Set up the SecretClient to return the expected secret
      _mockSecretClient.Setup(client => client.GetSecretAsync(certificateName, null, CancellationToken.None))
          .ReturnsAsync(() =>
          {
              return new KeyVaultSecret(certificateName, base64PrivateKey);
          });


      // Act
      X509Certificate2 actualCertificate = await _keyVaultManager.GetCertificateFromKeyVaultAsync(certificateName);

      // Assert
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedCertificate, actualCertificate); ;
}
```

Note: Here is the GetSecretAsync definition https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.getsecretasync?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: What is the definition of `GetSecretAsync`? Please edit the question so that it contains a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Here is the method definition https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient.getsecretasync?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

The `GetSecretAsync` method returns a `Task<Response<KeyVaultSecret>>`, so in order to use `ReturnsAsync`, you must supply a `Response<KeyVaultSecret>`, not just a `KeyVaultSecret`.

The [Response](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.response-1) class, it turns out, is an `abstract` class, so one option is to find one of the existing derived classes and use that to package the `KeyVaultSecret`.

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, and I also don't know that API, but another option is to also use Moq to create a return value:

```
mockSecretClient
    .Setup(client => client.GetSecretAsync(certificateName, null, CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync(new Mock<Response<KeyVaultSecret>>().Object);
```

This compiles.